# Flutter Integration with AdMob (iOS platform) failing - error related to GoogleServices

Tags: flutter, admob

I'm trying to add admob plugin to my flutter app. Its not going very well.

**What is the problem:**

For the iOS version, I'm receiving an error when I compile the app:

```
path: satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0
Configuring the default Firebase app...
6.11.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000004] App with name __FIRAPP_DEFAULT does not exist.
6.11.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000012] Could not locate configuration file: 'GoogleService-Info.plist'.
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c4f02e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff50b97b20 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c4ee6c +[NSException raise:format:] + 188
    3   Runner                              0x000000010c0a6d1a +[FIRApp configure] + 138
    4   Runner                              0x000000010c106cb2 -[FLTFirebaseAdMobPlugin init] + 258
    5   Runner                              0x000000010c106a26 +[FLTFirebaseAdMobPlugin registerWithRegistrar:] + 70
    6   Runner                              0x000000010c0944d0 +[GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:] + 112
    7   Runner                           <…>
```

**What is my configuration?**

Well , I've placed my GoogleService-Info.plist file in the same directory as my info.plist file. I'm not even sure if I need this for admob. This is only for analytics, and I do not need analytics.. do I?

For Android integration of Admob - it seems quite simple. 
What should I be doing?

I'm really lost. Not sure what else I can do.

**3. Packages added:**

In terms of my packages, here's what I'm using:

```
  firebase_admob: ^0.9.0+9
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.10
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.6
```

**4. Other Issues **

In the Podfile, should I uncomment:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'
```

? Perhaps I need lower models to work also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common thing which I forget to add GoogleService-Info.plist in Runner.xcworkspace

open Runner.xcworkspace right click on runner and choose add file select GoogleService-Info.plist